# C0209: Formatting a regular string which could be a f-string (consider-using-f-string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, pylintrc

For the below line, I am getting pylint issue: " C0209: Formatting a regular string which could be a f-string (consider-using-f-string)"

```
auth = str(base64.b64encode(bytes("%s:%s" % (self.user, self.password), "utf-8")), "ascii").strip()
```

I tried resolving it, but I am not sure if it is the right way to fix it. Can someone please advise?

```
auth = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(f'{self.user, self.password}', "utf-8")), "ascii").strip()
```

Comment: `f'{self.user}:{self.password}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auth = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(f'{self.user}:{self.password}', "utf-8")), "ascii").strip()
```

You may not be using the f-string correctly, change `f'{self.user, self.password}`' to `f'{self.user}:{self.password}'`

[More info](https://miguendes.me/pylint-consider-using-f-string)